# Queue-ing Byte arrays trouble

Tags: c#, queue

The simplest example. I'm trying to create queue of a byte arrays like that:

```
        Queue<Byte[]> q = new Queue<Byte[]>();
        Byte[] block = new Byte[1];
        block[0] = 1;
        q.Enqueue(block);
        block[0] = 2;
        q.Enqueue(block);
        block[0] = 3;
        q.Enqueue(block);
        byte[] block1 = q.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
        block1 = q.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
        block1 = q.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
```

But in fact I have all three blocks with "3", but expected "1" "2" "3". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're enqueueing the same array over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new array each time otherwise you're just changing the same one and adding multiple references of it into the `Queue`

```
Queue<Byte[]> q = new Queue<Byte[]>();
Byte[] block = new Byte[1];
block[0] = 1;
q.Enqueue(block);

// Create a new array
block = new Byte[1];
block[0] = 2;
q.Enqueue(block);

// Create a new array
block = new Byte[1];
block[0] = 3;
q.Enqueue(block);
byte[] block1 = q.Dequeue();
Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
block1 = q.Dequeue();
Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
block1 = q.Dequeue();
Console.WriteLine(block1[0]);
```